# Configuring Mac Server (El Capitan) DNS with Multiple Sites

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx, mac-osx-server

I am having trouble confusing multiple sites on Mac Server (El Capitan).

Under "Websites", I want to configure more than one domain. When I add the sites, there are not reachable (i.e. no green light).

[Websites Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hPqv.png)

It doesn't work when I activate "DNS" nor when I leave "DNS" off.

[DNS Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JLW0.png)

I have my domains registered at Hover with the DNS records on each domain pointing to my static IP.

Should I leave DNS on Mac Server ON or OFF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your domain's authorative server is not on your static IP, that is, your domain DNS is hosted elsewhere, then you don't need to have a DNS server.

You can check your NS record with `dig NS example.com`. This will show your domain's authorative name servers.

Then, you need to have DNS records set up for your virtual hosts. You can check these with `dig A example.com`. This should return your static IP address.

Comment: Thank you. Based on that, it appears my authoritative server is NOT on my static IP server. They are ns1.hover.com and ns2.hover.com (on Hover). So, in that case, I should turn off the DNS service on OSX Server. And simply have an A record on Hover's DNS settings pointing to my static IP. Is that correct? I have done that but still don't see my site working properly (no green light).

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Then the green light is related to something else.

Comment: Any idea on where I can start looking? This is a fresh installation of El Capitan. I just set up the server.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with hosting websites on a Mac platform. But to start, you would need to find out what this green / red light means exactly.